# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null on Input click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have this DIV provided below basically I am trying to append the similar row below it via button click. As my rows contain inputs tag so when I am clicking on the appended div input box getting an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null for the input

```
            <tbody class="tableBody">
                <tr class="p-2" id="row-item">
                    <td id="modelName">
                        <div class="form-outline search-box">
                            <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control" name="modelName[]" required />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form1">Model Name</label>
                            <div class="result"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="quntity">
                        <div class="form-outline">
                            <input type="number" min="1" id="qty" name="qty[]" class="form-control" required
                                autocomplete="off" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="qty">Quantity</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="price-total" class="priceTotal">
                        <div class="form-outline">
                            <input type="number" id="totalprice" readonly name="totalprice[]" class="form-control"
                                required autocomplete="off" />
                            <input style="display: none;" type="number" name="category[]" id="category" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary add-row">+</button></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
```

and the JS code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var add_button = $(".add-row"); //Add button ID

    var max_fields = 200; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $("#row-item"); //Fields wrapper
    //Content to clone
    var clone_content =
        '<tr class="p-2" id="row-item"> <td id="modelName"> <div class="form-outline search-box"> <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control" name="modelName[]" required /> <label class="form-label"for="form1">Model Name</label><div class="result"></div></div></td><td id="quntity"><div class="form-outline"><input type="number"min="1"id="qty"name="qty[]"class="form-control"required autocomplete="off"/><label class="form-label"for="qty">Quantity</label></div></td><td id="price-total"class="priceTotal"><div class="form-outline"><input type="number"id="totalprice"readonly name="totalprice[]"class="form-control"required autocomplete="off"/><input style="display: none;"type="number"name="category[]"id="category"value=""/></div></td><td><button id="close">X</button></td></tr>';
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    $(add_button).on('click', function() { //on add input button click
        $('.tableBody').append(clone_content);
    });
```

The Variable `clone_content` contains the div code which I want to add again.

[The Red Circle is the original Table row and yellow highlighted is the div which was added via js. But i don't know why it is missing borders of the input and when I click on the input box the error is shown in the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSzI.png)

Comment: I am not getting an error with your code

Comment: Same as @JohnTyner, are you trying to change the style of an HTML element anywhere in your JS file at all?

Comment: @thursday_dan yes I have added a button in the last row. But I also tried to keep the same HTML still it was showing an error.

Comment: @Kinglish Once you click on  the input box which was added via JS then there is an error in console.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to access the style of an element? I don't see the style property in the example you've posted unless I'm missing it?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes. I have updated the question with an image.Please check that

Comment: @thursday_dan No, I am not using any style property. I just want an additional tr with inputs to collect data. Please check the question I have added an image of the output.

Comment: @MuditKhandelwal very strange, I've managed to get it working in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/thursdaydan/pen/vYxGpvo) with no errors.

Comment: @thursday_dan Thanks I got the issue. It was due to the style framework which i was using :
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.3.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Thanks You! : )

Answer (score 0):

The Error is due to the CSS framework which I have used. If I remove the CDN it works completely fine. I don't know why it happened but it's working now.

Anyone know why let me know.

Comment: I've added the stylesheet to the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/thursdaydan/pen/vYxGpvo). I'd check your load order and ensure all of your bootstrap components are being loaded correctly.